# change variable when window is resized

Tags: jquery

This code works perfectly:

```
var size = function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        return '2'
    } else {
        return '3'
    }
}();
```

But I wanted to to it with window resize but not working:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    var size = function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            return '2'
        } else {
            return '3'
        }
    }();
});
```

Comment: What is _not working_?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/aE9qU/

Comment: It's working, but you have to do something with the variable. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRNxQ/) for basic example of alerting its value (resize the window to see it in action). If you don't do anything, well, you won't see anything happening.

Comment: `on` does not allow multiple events, but `bind` does. See new answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function checkWidth(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        alert('2');
    } else {
        alert('3');
    }
}
$(function(){
    checkWidth();
});
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    checkWidth();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sf5Mt/)

Comment: This is not necessary. You just needed to replace `on` with `bind` and it would have allowed for multiple events with no other change.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QcKB9/13/

great example of how to mess with jquery/resize stuff..

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
 resizeTimer = setTimeout(myResize, 50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegated version of `on` does not allow multiple event types.

The bind method does however allow multiple event names, so you can simply change `on` to `bind` and your code will work as-is (including the run on first load you wanted):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/aE9qU/2/

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function () {

    var size = function () {

        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            return '2'
        } else {
            return '3'
        }
    }();
    console.log(size);
});
```

Note I changed the default JSFiddle+Jquery behavior to match your code (that is not wrap it in an onload, otherwise it would not work).